# Exclude Kubernetes Metrics monitoring in prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

We are monitoring our Kubernetes clusters metrics through Prometheus. It is working fine but we dont want monitor all default metrics. Just want to monitor few selected metrics. How do I exclude unwanted metrics from prometheus.

We are using the below version K8:

`1.18.6`

Installed Prometheus usning helm chart:

`helm repo add prometheus-community https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-chart`

`helm search repo prometheus-community-new/prometheus`

`helm install prometheus-community/prometheus --generate-name --namespace prometheus`

where should I disable these metrics in helm.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> How do I exclude unwanted metrics from prometheus.

With the commands you used, Helm will apply the defaults as defined in the [values.yaml](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/105231668de0575865c7749fcc9998d18daa83f3/charts/prometheus/values.yaml#L1331) of said chart. You want to redefine (replace) the jobs under `serverFiles.prometheus.yml.scrape_configs` by removing any jobs using the [Kubernetes service discovery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#kubernetes_sd_config) that you're not interested in and/or by adjusting the [relabling](https://training.promlabs.com/training/relabeling/training-overview/introduction) directives to your needs.